# Django NoReverseMatch URL redirect

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to customize the signup redirect url using allauth in django 3. I am getting this error, instead:

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/candidate-signup/

Reverse for 'candidate_profile' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/profile/(?P<username>[^/]+)/$']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

from .models import CandidateProfile
from .forms import CandidateProfileForm

from allauth.account import app_settings
from allauth.account.views import SignupView
from allauth.account.utils import complete_signup
from allauth.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse


class CandidateSignUpView(SignupView, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.user = form.save(self.request)
        self.user.is_candidate = True
        self.user.save()
        success_url = f'profile/{self.user.username}/'
        try:
            return complete_signup(
                self.request,
                self.user,
                app_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION,
                self.success_url,
            )
        except ImmediateHttpResponse as e:
            return e.response
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('candidate-signup/', views.CandidateSignUpView.as_view(), name='candidate_signup'),
    path('company-signup/', views.CompanySignUpView.as_view(), name='company_signup'),
    path('profile/<str:username>/', views.CandidateProfileView.as_view(), name='candidate_profile'),
]
```

django/conf/global_settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'candidate_profile'
```

html

```
                <form class="signup" id="signup_form" method="post" action="{% url 'candidate_signup' %}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    {% if redirect_field_value %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="{{ redirect_field_name }}" value="{{ redirect_field_value }}" />
                    {% endif %}
```

A working solution would redirect from the signup page to `/accounts/profile/<str:username>/`

Comment: this problem usually is for paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in `CandidateSignUpView`:

1. You're passing `self.success_url` to `complete_signup`, instead of passing `success_url`, which is defined locally in `form_valid` method. As `self.success_url` is `None` (it is defined in `SignupView` and inherited in your `CandidateSignUpView`), `complete_signup` is receiving `None` for `success_url` parameter, so it uses default `success_url` after login.
2. You should better not construct urls manually. For this you'd better use `reverse` and pass view name and according arguments, so instead of `success_url = f'profile/{self.user.username}/'` you'd better use `success_url = reverse('candidate_profile',kwargs={'username':self.user.username})`. See more about `reverse` [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse).

So, your `CandidateSignUpView` should be something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import View

from .models import CandidateProfile
from .forms import CandidateProfileForm

from allauth.account.views import SignupView
from allauth.account.utils import complete_signup
from allauth.exceptions import ImmediateHttpResponse
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.urls.base import reverse


class CandidateSignUpView(SignupView, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.user = form.save(self.request)
        self.user.is_candidate = True
        self.user.save()
        # success_url = f'profile/{self.user.username}/'
        success_url = reverse('candidate_profile',kwargs={'username':self.user.username})
        
        try:
            return complete_signup(
                self.request,
                self.user,
                app_settings.EMAIL_VERIFICATION,
                # self.success_url,
                success_url
            )
        except ImmediateHttpResponse as e:
            return e.response
```